# Estimating Variance of Geometric Growth Function

Tags: probability-theory

I am having a hard time calculating the variance of the following function??

$f(x_n)=f(x_{n-1})(1+\alpha (1/m)+\beta\epsilon_n\sqrt (1/m)) $

Hence, $f(x_n)=f(x_0)\prod_1^n(1+\alpha (1/m)+\beta\epsilon_n\sqrt (1/m)) $

Where $\epsilon \sim N(0,1)$ is i.i.d $\lor n$ and $1\leq n\leq m$ and $\alpha$ & $\beta$ are positive constants. Let $f(x_0)=1$ in this example

Here is as far as I have gotten:

In order for me to calculate the variance, I need to calculate the expectations of $f(x_n)$. My problem is the function is geometric not linear. So, I tried logging the function, to break the terms up into linear pieces.

So $ln(f(x_n))=lnf(x_0)+\sum_1^n ln(1+\alpha (1/m)+\beta\epsilon_n\sqrt (1/m))$

But since the log function is concave, I would somehow have to introduce Jensen's Inequality.
The other way I tried doing it is by taking the expectation at each $n$ and try to see a pattern,

$E(f(x_1))=f(x_0)+f(x_0)\alpha (1/m)+0=f(x_0)(1+\alpha (1/m))    $

$E(f(x_2))=f(x_0)(1+\alpha (1/m))+f(x_0)(1+\alpha (1/m))\alpha (1/m)+0=f(x_0)(1+\alpha (1/m))^2$

...
Which would lead to,
$E(f(x_n))=f(x_0)(1+\alpha (1/m))^n$
if I am right.

Comment: At all cost, do not reply to the people who post answers to your questions! Who knows, you might even *learn* something in the process...

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite this as $z_n=z_{n-1}y_n$ where $z_n=f(x_n)$ and $y_n=1+\alpha/m+\beta\epsilon_n/\sqrt{m}$, thus, $(y_n)$ is i.i.d. such that $E(y_1)=\gamma$ with $\gamma=1+\alpha/m$ and $\mathrm{var}(y_1)=\beta^2/m$.

If $x_0$ is independent of $(\epsilon_n)$, one gets $E(z_n)=E(z_{n-1})E(y_n)$, that is, 
$$E(f(x_n))=\gamma^nE(f(x_0)).
$$
Likewise, $E(z_n^2)=E(z_{n-1}^2)E(y_n^2)$, that is, $E(z_n^2)=E(z_{0}^2)E(y_1^2)^n$. Since $E(y_1^2)=\mathrm{var}(y_1)+E(y_1)^2$, this yields
$$
\mathrm{var}(f(x_n))=(\gamma^2+\beta^2/m)^nE(f(x_{0})^2)-\gamma^{2n}E(f(x_{0}))^2.
$$